# pictureBox.ImageLocation Can't retrieve HTMLElement

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, picturebox

I'm trying to take a picture element from a website and display it inside a PictureBox.. The code doesn't return any errors, but nothing is displayed.

I'm using a WebBrowser class and trying to display the elements using an event that invokes once the webpage is done loading

```
                void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender,       WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = wb.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_mainContent_identityBar_emblemImg").InnerText; // does nothing       
        label1.Text = "Last Played: " + wb.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_mainContent_lastPlayedLabel").InnerText; // works fine
    }
```

Here's an example of the webpage I'm trying to pull the image from: http://halo.bungie.net/Stats/Halo3/Default.aspx?player=SmitherdxA27
^It's the bird with the orange background on that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```
private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://halo.bungie.net/Stats/Halo3/Default.aspx?player=SmitherdxA27");
}

private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Url.ToString() == "http://halo.bungie.net/Stats/Halo3/Default.aspx?player=SmitherdxA27"))
    {
        HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_mainContent_identityStrip_EmblemCtrl_imgEmblem");
        string src = elem.GetAttribute("src");
        this.pictureBox1.ImageLocation = src;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried running the following code: http://pastebin.com/TUV6xABS with nothing but a pictureBox on my form1.. I didn't get any errors but nothing was displayed, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is very strange. Set a breakpoint, get the src, copy it and paste it on the browser and see if the image gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It returns nothing because an image tag doesnt contain inner text. You need to use the the element and generate a bitmap.

```
public Bitmap GetImage(string id)
    {
        HtmlElement e = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(id);
        IHTMLImgElement img = (IHTMLImgElement)e.DomElement;
        IHTMLElementRenderFixed render = (IHTMLElementRenderFixed)img;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(e.OffsetRectangle.Width, e.OffsetRectangle.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
        render.DrawToDC(hdc);
        g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);

        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting errors on IHTMLImgElement and IHTMLElementRenderFixed, saying they don't exist, what namespaces do I need?